# How to grep for a pattern followed by a number and print to file if number than x,

Tags: grep

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Thispeculiarpattern(1.00);thatpeculiarpattern(0.90);....
Thispeculiarpattern(0.73);thatpeculiarpattern(0.15);...................

Somerandomtext(0.81); somemorerandomtext(0.79):.................................
Somerandomtext(0.62); somemorerandomtext(0.04):..............
Herewegoagain(0.93);Herewegoyetagain(0.48);....
Herewegoagain(0.71);Herewegoyetagain(0.87);....
```

and I would like an output like this:

```
Thispeculiarpattern(1.00);thatpeculiarpattern(0.90);....
Somerandomtext(0.81); somemorerandomtext(0.79):....
Herewegoagain(0.71);Herewegoyetagain(0.87);....
```

I.e, I want all lines output to file IF they contain either "Thispeculiarpattern", "Somerandomtext" or "Herewegoyetagain" which MUST then be followed by a parenthesis with a value of 0.8 or above.

Comment: But your output has value less than 0.8.

Comment: Can the numbers be negative or be formatted as `1.3e-8`?

Comment: Sorry if it is unclear, but if you see my last line of explanation, you can see that I want the last line because of "Herewegoyetagain" which MUST then be followed by a parenthesis with a value of 0.8. The "Herewegoyetagain(0.71)" is merely "hitch-hiking" on the same line. :)

Comment: @ChristofferBuggeHarder I believe that you meant to write: 'The "Herewegoagain(0.71)" is merely "hitch-hiking" on the same line.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all of your numbers are, as shown in the examples, fixed-point decimal:

#### Using grep

```
$ grep -E '(Thispeculiarpattern|Somerandomtext|Herewegoyetagain)\(([1-9]|0\.[89])' file
Thispeculiarpattern(1.00);thatpeculiarpattern(0.90);....
Somerandomtext(0.81); somemorerandomtext(0.79):.................................
Herewegoagain(0.71);Herewegoyetagain(0.87);....
```

#### Using sed

```
$ sed -En '/(Thispeculiarpattern|Somerandomtext|Herewegoyetagain)\(([1-9]|0\.[89])/p' file
Thispeculiarpattern(1.00);thatpeculiarpattern(0.90);....
Somerandomtext(0.81); somemorerandomtext(0.79):.................................
Herewegoagain(0.71);Herewegoyetagain(0.87);....
```

#### Using awk

```
$ awk '/(Thispeculiarpattern|Somerandomtext|Herewegoyetagain)\(([1-9]|0\.[89])/' file
Thispeculiarpattern(1.00);thatpeculiarpattern(0.90);....
Somerandomtext(0.81); somemorerandomtext(0.79):.................................
Herewegoagain(0.71);Herewegoyetagain(0.87);....
```

#### How it works

In all cases, we look for lines that match the regex

```
(Thispeculiarpattern|Somerandomtext|Herewegoyetagain)\(([1-9]|0\.[89])
```

This regex breaks down into two parts.  The first is:

```
(Thispeculiarpattern|Somerandomtext|Herewegoyetagain)\(
```

The above matches any of your three strings followed by `(`.

The second part is:

```
([1-9]|0\.[89])
```

This matches any number which starts with a digit 1 through 9 **or** a number with starts with `0.8` or `0.9`

Comment: John, thank you so very much! It worked beautifully. And it was indeed thoroughly explained - I am humbly impressed by the thoroughness and carefulness of your answer. I must read up on my old regular expressions.